# UITableViewCell Creation

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uitableview

Hey guys I have a button (+) in the right `navigationBarItem`, I am trying to make a function where when you click this button, you create a `cell` in the `UITableViewCell`, and you can give it a `title` and an *image*.

Comment: show your data source code which you are using for your table view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by creating a struct to represent your cell's data.

```
struct Object {
    var image: UIImage!
    var title: String!
}
```

Then you can have an array of `Object` to be your table view's data source.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties

    var object: Object?
    var objects: [Object] = []
    var picker: UIImagePickerController!

    // MARK: Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker?.allowsEditing = false
        picker?.delegate = self
        picker?.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return objects.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        let object = objects[indexPath.row]

        cell.imageView?.image = object.image ?? UIImage()
        cell.textLabel?.text = object.title ?? ""

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        switch info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        case let .some(image):
            object?.image = image
        default:
            break
        }

        picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.showCellTitleAlert()
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

        object = nil

        dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // MARK: Alerts

    private func showCellTitleAlert() {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Cell Title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addTextField { $0.placeholder = "Title" }
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) {
            self.object = nil
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { _ in
            self.object?.title = alert.textFields?.first.flatMap { $0.text }
            self.object.flatMap { self.objects.append($0) }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func didSelectCreateButton() {

        object = Object()

        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

You will need an image picker for the user to choose an image and you can use an alert view to take user input for the title. By conforming to the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`, you can detect when an image has been picked or if the user canceled.

When the create button is pressed, we create an empty object and present the picker. After we populate the object with the chosen image, we present the text field alert view. If the save button is pressed, the object is added to the data source and the table view is reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the value in datasource and use `tableView.reloadData()`. This will reload the table and add a new cell to the table. Accordingly you can give it a title and image too.

Answer (score 1):

Just Update the count of data source

1. Create a variable

   ```
   var rowCount:Int = 0
   ```
2. Add a function to change the variable value

   ```
   @IBAction func addCell(sender:AnyObject) {

      rowCount = rowCount + 1
      tableView.reloadData()
   }
   ```
3. In the datasource delegate method of table view, use this variable

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
   {
       return rowCount
   }
   ```
4. Set title and image in the delegate method

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       //add logic here
       return cell
   }
   ```